# Threads in java v/s pthreads

Tags: java, multithreading, pthreads

When i start a java application, i see it running as a process on my machine. If this java application creates threads, are they mapped to native threads on the OS (similar to threads created using pthreads)?

Comment: This is out of scope for StackOverflow, but generally yes, all modern systems use native processes for implementing threads.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888160/distinguish-java-threads-and-os-threads